# Birt Chart Engine Documentation

Tags: java, charts, swt, birt

I am looking for a complete, precise and accurate documentation about Birt Chart Engine but I cant find anything, all documentations I have encountered are more Birt Designer related or inaccurate or even inexistante. I hope someone can help me...

(I precise that I particularly look for a documentation about chart interactivity and scripting while being rendered as SWT content and made fully with Java code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the API docs can be found [here](http://www.birt-exchange.org/documentation/BIRT_220/ChartJavadoc/chart/api/index.html), which are precise and accurate regarding the various classes and how they can be used.

Comment: Yes I knew this site but it is frequently inaccurate like
<hr />
<h2>TOGGLE_DATA_POINT_VISIBILITY</h2>
<b>public static final int </b>TOGGLE_DATA_POINT_VISIBILITY

    The '<i>Toggle Data Point Visibility</i>' literal value.

<u>    If the meaning of 'Toggle Data Point Visibility' literal object isn't clear, there really should be more of a description here... </u>
<hr />

Comment: woops looks like he doesn't like html tags :/

Answer (score 2):

First, BIRT cannot render interactively like you've seen in demos on Actuate's website -- that is a web-based program that they sell -- it may have misled you. It can run from a .WAR on a server and feed some AJAX code or whatever.

Second, there is no good, up-to-date, free documentation for BIRT, as far as I can find in three weeks of searching. The API docs are quite lacking with respect to integrating BIRT with your own application or extending its capabilities. I have found the "Integrating and Extending BIRT" book by Jason Weathersby et al to be marginally helpful -- it is available for "rent" online through Safari Books Online.

Mostly you'll need to do lots of Google searches to find what you're looking for. The code examples are quite necessary to follow, since there are a lot of nit-picky details that will hurt you.

Comment: First, Birt (FREE version) has some (very usefull) interactivity features when you are ready to fight the lack of documentations. The examples I talked about weren't some Flash show of another product, I still can make difference between a flash show and SWT rendered Birt example I tweaked. For documentation, it's a challenge to find something but you confess you only searched for 3 weeks (Birt is a complex framework). And thanks for the google advice, I never knew it helped people "find what they are looking for"...(do I look that stupide as not to use google before posting on this site ?)

Comment: I intended no offence or disrespect. I certainly don't think you're stupid. But three weeks of Google searching is A LOT for me. I've been working in IT for more than 10 years (started in high school), using the advanced features of search engines since 1998, and I usually find what I'm looking for within 2 hours. It was as if I had found that I needed to write 5,000 lines of code to say "Hello, cruel world!" with BIRT. :-)  

With respect to the interactivity question, I'm guessing you're talking about the server rendered version. With the Eclipse preview mode you can't change runtime stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by server rendered version ? I am just talking about some charts (with or without axis) rendered as SWT to fit in a (local if I have to precise) Eclipse RCP application.Of course I dont speak about the the Eclipse preview. I really speak about a chart,that in my case came along with an swt table,my table fed my chart and selecting my chart selected my table rows, it was just a tiny example of interactivity but I could have done much more with a lot of work, like resizing my rows or swaping them...It is not because you did not find something that you can say it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

The book [Integrating And Extending Birt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321443853) has a nice chapter on how to progamm using the BIRT Charting API.